# Should my Chef Server server show up as a node?

Tags: chef-infra

In the process of creating and setting up my Chef infrastructure on my own servers, I have noticed that my server is showing up as a node. My first question: is this normal and correct?

For example, server-001 is my Chef Server. The rest are intended to be managed nodes:

```
$ knife node list
  server-001.example.com
  server-002.example.com
  server-003.example.com
  server-004.example.com
  server-005.example.com
```

This seems strange and possibly incorrect to me. My second question, if this is normal, why would a Chef Server want to keep a reference to itself as a node?

Question #3: if this is incorrect, any ideas on what I did to make this happen? (Some background: I followed the Chef Server setup directions and then bootstrapped the other nodes. I have not explicitly created any nodes.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this strikes you as incorrect? You will (probably) want to manage the node your Chef server is on with chef, right?
It keeps a reference to itself as a node because running chef-client on the machine running the server is no different than running it from any other node.

Comment: It seems incorrect to me because it breaks the principle of least surprise. If I did want to manage the chef server from chef server, I would be explicit about adding it as a node -- it should not happen by default. Why?... there is an extra node around which gets in the way -- something to accidentally clobber. I'm still not sure (part 3 of my question) what caused it to get registered as a node in the first place. (When I was brand new to chef, I didn't know if it was safe to remove. I just removed it.)

Comment: Nils, have you found part of the documentation -- or code -- that supports what you said ("It keeps a reference to itself as a node")? I ask because I have not found such documentation.

Comment: I have not yet. I'm planning to do a full chef server install on the weekend.
My gut says the node might be created when you create the client.

I believe updating the documentation was one of the priority tasks after ChefConf :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I have not found any documentation regarding this.  
But it happens for me too when I install from debian packages, or with the omnibus installer.